# ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError when parsing rsyncd config file with global options

Tags: python, rsync, configparser

A configuration file generally needs section headers for each section. In [rsyncd config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf) files a global section need not explicitly have a section header. Example of an rsyncd.conf file:

[rsyncd.conf]

```
# GLOBAL OPTIONS

path            = /data/ftp
pid file        = /var/run/rsyncdpid.pid
syslog facility = local3
uid             = rsync
gid             = rsync
read only       = true
use chroot      = true

# MODULE OPTIONS
[mod1]
...
```

How to parse such config files using python `ConfigParser`?
Doing the following gives an erorr:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> cp = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> cp.read("rsyncd.conf")

# Error: ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex Martelli [provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/2819788#2819788) for using ConfigParser to parse similar files (which are section less files).
His solution is a file-like wrapper that will automatically insert a dummy section.

You can apply the above solution to parsing rsyncd config files.

```
>>> class FakeGlobalSectionHead(object):
...     def __init__(self, fp):
...         self.fp = fp
...         self.sechead = '[global]\n'
...     def readline(self):
...         if self.sechead:
...             try: return self.sechead
...             finally: self.sechead = None
...         else: return self.fp.readline()
...
>>> cp = ConfigParser()
>>> cp.readfp(FakeGlobalSectionHead(open('rsyncd.conf')))
>>> print(cp.items('global'))
[('path', '/data/ftp'), ('pid file', '/var/run/rsyncdpid.pid'), ...]
```

Comment: With the deprecation of `configparser#readfp` this answer, whilst excellent, is likely to stop working in future versions of Python. The `itertools#chain` answer is probably a better solution for newer Python versions.

Comment: readfp was replace by read_file: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file

Answer (score 18):

I use `itertools.chain` (Python 3):

```
import configparser, itertools
cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
filename = 'foo.ini'
with open(filename) as fp:
  cfg.read_file(itertools.chain(['[global]'], fp), source=filename)
print(cfg.items('global'))
```

(`source=filename` results in better error messages, especially if you read from multiple config files.)

Comment: Nice! This solved my problem and taught me a nice Python trick. Thanks!