# How to parse a file in a key=value format

Tags: python

I've got a text file in the format

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

What would be the best way to read it in so I have access to the values in a form like `myObject.key1` or `myObject["key1"]`?

Comment: I wonder if [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/configparser.html) would be useful here... I've never used it myself.

Comment: Oh, yes.  configparser is a *very* helpful module.  You can have `key=value` or `key:value`.

Comment: configparser could be useful but only if you are able do reformat the text file a bit. The text file has to look a bit different...
In particular afaik you need to define some sections...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse key value pairs in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161439/parse-key-value-pairs-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myObject = {}
with open("something.ini") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    key, value = line.rstrip("\n").split("=")
    myObject[key] = value
```

Note that, as @Goodies mentioned below, if you assign to the same key multiple times, this will just take the last value. It is however trivial to add some error handing:

```
myObject = {}
with open("something.ini") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    key, value = line.rstrip("\n").split("=")
    if(not key in myObject):
      myObject[key] = value
    else:
      print "Duplicate assignment of key '%s'" % key
```

Comment: Almost too simple and works. Keep in mind that if you have a duplicate, it will take the last value.

Answer (score 3):

The classic one liner ...

```
x = dict((kv.split('=') for kv in (l.strip('\n') for l in open('hello.txt'))))
```

Which results in:

```
{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary if I were you. Try this if your application accept the use of dictionaries.

```
with open('your_file_name') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

myDict = {}    

for line in content:
    a, b = line.split('=')
    myDict += {a:int(b)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with regular expressions

```
import re

with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    matches = re.findall(r'^(.+)=(.*)$', f.read(), flags=re.M)
    d = dict(matches)

print d['key']
```

Be aware that if you have duplicate keys in your file, the last one found is going to shadow the others.

If you want to be able to do `d.key3`, you can use the [`bunch`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.1) package

```
from bunch import Bunch

d = Bunch(matches)
print d.key3
```