# Python - Read value of variable from file

Tags: python

In bash, I have a file that stores my passwords in variable format.

e.g.

```
cat file.passwd
password1=EncryptedPassword1
password2=EncryptedPassword2
```

Now if I want to use the value of `password1`, this is all that I need to do in bash.

```
grep password1 file.passwd  | cut -d'=' -f2
```

I am looking for an alternative for this in python. Is there any library that gives functionality to simply extract the value or do we have to do it manually 
 like below?

```
with open(file, 'r') as input:
         for line in input:
             if 'password1' in line:
                 re.findall(r'=(\w+)', line)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse key value pairs in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161439/parse-key-value-pairs-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file and add the check statement:

```
if line.startswith("password1"):
    print re.findall(r'=(\w+)',line)
```

**Code**:

```
import re
with open(file,"r") as input:
    lines = input.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("password1"):
            print re.findall(r'=(\w+)',line)
```

Comment: Why not just `for line in input:`? (Although giving `input` a different name so it didn't overwrite the built-in would be good)

Comment: just to give a simple approach here. although should use different name.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you've written. If you want to play code golf:

```
line = next(line for line in open(file, 'r') if 'password1' in line)
```

Comment: line = next(line.strip().split('=')[1] for line in open('mout.txt', 'r') if 'password1' in line)  if you just want the password returned

Answer (score 0):

I found this [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) very useful ! Made life much easier.

Comment: Do not consider adding only links in your solution, there are prone to be removed.