# How to read text file line by line and save values into variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to read my parameter file line by line and save the values into a variable my parameter file look something like that

Parameter File

```
DBHOSTNAME=192.168.x.x
DBSID=SID
BEUSERNAME=username
BEUSERPASSWORD=password
HOSTPATHBE=path
```

Code

```
file = open('envparam.config')
    for line in file:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        print (fields[0])
```

So far I am able to read my parameter file but not able to store values into variables can anyone help me with this

Comment: What have you written to try and "store values into a variables"?  What would you want the result of executing your program to be?

Comment: @Scott Hunter my program should should store the values of DBHOSTNAME,DBSID,BEUSERNAME,BEUSERPASSWORD&HOSTPATHBE

Comment: store them into a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse key value pairs in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is consistent, this will store your info in a dictionary:

```
with open('envparam.config') as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('=')
        data[key] = value
```

You can then access it like this:

```
>>> data['DBSID']
SID
```

Comment: it showing IndentationError: unexpected indent on line 2

Comment: yes this code works now i want to save these values in a varible for exmple if i print DBSID it should shows the value of DBSID

Comment: They are already stored in the dictionary. Try `print(data['DBSID'])`

Comment: it showng error when i am trying to print the value of DBSID error  print(data['DBSID'])
KeyError: 'DBSID'

Comment: can you help me with this

Comment: You have to print outside the loop, when all the entries have been processed

Answer (score -1):

To create a list with a line as each element, use the .split() method with "\n"(the newline character)

```
file = open('envparam.config').split('\n')
```